# CSRF doesn't work on the first post attempt

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, csrf

This is my first time implementing CSRF and first time posting on Stack. I've struggled through the CSRF config, but finally got something that almost works.

If I open a bookmarked page in a fresh browser and submit a form, I'm seeing a 403 Invalid CSRF error: EBADCSRFTOKEN. In this case, the user auth is cookied so it does not challenge. I wonder if the session is expired? Subsequent posts work fine. Get requests are all fine. I'm stumped, time to put this challenge aside and ask for help as I've been at it for way too long, would appreciate any help.

Server.js does not reference csrf middleware but sets up the session

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const favicon = require("serve-favicon");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const flash = require("connect-flash");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const logger = require("morgan");
const expressSession = require("express-session");
const setCurrentUser = require("./app/controllers/setCurrentUser");

var session = {
  secret: "XXXHIDDENXXX",
  cookie: {},
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
};

app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, "public/images", "favicon.png")));
app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(flash());
app.use(expressSession(session));
app.use("/public", express.static("public"));
app.use(setCurrentUser);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.user = req.user;
  res.locals.success = req.flash("success");
  res.locals.error = req.flash("error");
  next();
});
```

Index.js

```
"use strict";

var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
const csrf = require("csurf");
const isLoggedIn = require("../controllers/auth");

var csrfProtection = csrf({ cookie: true });

router.use(csrf({ cookie: true }));

router.use((req, res, next) => {
  // generate one CSRF token to every render page
  res.locals.token = req.csrfToken();
  next();
});

router.get("/settings", isLoggedIn, csrfProtection, function (req, res, next) {
  ...
});

router.post("/settings", isLoggedIn, csrfProtection, function (req, res, next) {
  ...
});
```

Interface, i'm using EJS, relevant code:

```
<head>
<meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="<%= locals.token %>">
</head>

<form method="POST" action="/settings">
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= locals.token %>">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="displayName">Name</label>
<input type="text" name="displayName" id="displayName" maxlength='30' data-parsley-maxlength='30' class="form-control" value="<%= user.displayName %>" required>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The above code renders as expected:

```
<meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token">
<meta name="csrf-token" content="qBdXd2ZQ-8vnbyw_IUivar_6UKp0qvhUf290">
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="qBdXd2ZQ-8vnbyw_IUivar_6UKp0qvhUf290">
```

Token is sent via the form post in the post data as _csrf: qBdXd2ZQ-8vnbyw_IUivar_6UKp0qvhUf290

Comment: Unrelated tip: You're using `const` properly, so also use `let` (instead of `var`).

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT 1

#### TL;DR

You use csrf middleware twice in cookie mode, it make express set cookie twice at the first time. (you could see there are two tokens)
You give your ejs `token1`, but your express validate it with `token2` in this line `app.use(csrf({ cookie: true }))`.

That's why invalid token happened.
But, it only happen **at the first time** because root cause depend on the implementation of csurf package.
You could see explanation to get more detail if you want to know the root cause.

```js
app.use(csrf({ cookie: true }))
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  // token1
  res.locals.token = req.csrfToken();
  next();
});
const csrfProtection = csrf({ cookie: true })
//                   token2 
app.get('/settings', csrfProtection, function (req, res) {
  res.render('send')
})
```

#### So how to fix it?

Remove `var csrfProtection = csrf({ cookie: true });` this line.
And remove the middleware in your router which is "settings"

From

```
router.get("/settings", isLoggedIn, csrfProtection, function (req, res, next) {
  ...
});
```

To

```
router.get("/settings", isLoggedIn, function (req, res, next) {
  ...
});
```

#### Explaination

Sorry for pasting this long code, but I need it to explain why your code is broken in first time post.

Please see mark1 and mark2 in following code.

Mark1: you use `app.use(csrf({ cookie: true }))` that means you provide a middleware for rest of router no matter path matches or not.

Mark2: you only provide the `csrfProtection` in your specific router which is "/settings" path, not rest of router.

What if you use it together?
Express will set-cookie **twice** for you **in the first time**.

[image]

```js
// server.js
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const csrf = require('csurf')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const express = require('express')
const session = require("express-session")
const app = express()
const sess = {
  secret: 'Key',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: {}
}
app.set("view engine", "ejs")
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(session(sess))

// ====> mark1
app.use(csrf({ cookie: true }))
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.token = req.csrfToken();
  next();
});

// ====> mark2
const csrfProtection = csrf({ cookie: true })

// ====> mark2
app.get('/settings', csrfProtection, function (req, res) {
  res.render('send')
})

// ====> mark2
app.post('/settings', csrfProtection,  function (req, res) {
  res.send('data is being processed')
})
app.listen(8080)
```

```html
<!-- my send.ejs -->
<form method="POST" action="/settings">
  <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= locals.token %>">
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

That's why you got the invalid csrf token in first time.

Then look at source code of the csurf.
It will use `setSecret` method when `secret` is `null` or `undefined` which is happening at first time.
And you could see csurf use `setHeader` here.

```js
// here, it's a middleware you used.
return function csrf (req, res, next) {
  // .... other code

  // generate & set secret
  if (!secret) {
    secret = tokens.secretSync()
    setSecret(req, res, sessionKey, secret, cookie)
  }
}

// setSecret will go to this method
function setCookie (res, name, val, options) {
  var data = Cookie.serialize(name, val, options)

  var prev = res.getHeader('set-cookie') || []
  var header = Array.isArray(prev) ? prev.concat(data)
    : [prev, data]

  res.setHeader('set-cookie', header)
}
```

You could add `console.log("secret: " + secret)` in line 105 in index.js of csurf modules
then you'll see the following log which **set-cookie is triggered twice**.

```
secret: undefined
secret: undefined
```

That's why your first time post is broken because you use both following methods at the same time.

```js
// ====> method1
app.use(csrf({ cookie: true }))
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.token = req.csrfToken();
  next();
});

// ====> method2
const csrfProtection = csrf({ cookie: true })
app.get('/settings', csrfProtection, function (req, res) {
  res.render('send')
})
```

### Original Answer

I'm not sure what you're looking for.

But if you're talking about why `GET` request is not protected by `csurf` , because `GET` request is ignored by `csurf` in default.
You could see the source code at [here](https://github.com/expressjs/csurf/blob/master/index.js#L57)

```js
// ignored methods
var ignoreMethods = opts.ignoreMethods === undefined
    ? ['GET', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS']
    : opts.ignoreMethods
```

By the way, `GET` request is usually used in read-only operations.

[OWASP CSRF](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html) says

> Do not use GET requests for state changing operations.

I think that is a reason why `csurf` doesn't protect the `GET` request in default.

Comment: I understand why GET requests are working but thank you for the explaination. I'm trying to figure out why my first post in a new session fails. .. but now I'm wondering if I have a session but it is expired and doesn't get a new one until the next refresh or post. So basically, maybe the failed post is happening because I have an expired session.

Comment: Could you reproduce this situation again? Or it's just happening occasionally?

Comment: You could debug by insert some console.log into index.js in csurf package (line 110-112 in index.js) to look the csrf value when you get the invalid csrf token in first time post.

Comment: Your code is fine. But if you don't set the maxAge for cookie, it never expired. So it could not be expired problem.

Comment: I'm able to reproduce, I found that it's fixed if I change csrf({ cookie: true }) to false. So I believe it has to do with a conflict of using sessions and cookies to validate the cookie. In the documentation it suggests to use one or the other: http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/csurf.html

Comment: @hangrycaterpillar Hi I'm also reproduce it, and i found the bug. You could take a look my updated answer.