# How to solve: "ForbiddenError: invalid csrf token"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, csrf

I have problems with setting up csrf. I hope that someone can point me in the right direction.

I'm using next.js with express.js.

When I refresh the page following happens:

1. I get a _csurf cookie (dev tools > application > cookies)
2. a csrf token is logged in my console (-> see last code snipped from context)
3. when I make a POST request (-> see routes/index.js f.ex. "/aignupQ"), I get the error "Invalid csurf token"; in the request header I can see the _csrf cookie
4. when I refresh the page and make the POST request again everything works.

I'm really confused by the error and really don't understand what is wrong. Here is some relevant code:

server.js:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const next = require("next");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const routes = require('./routes');

const csrf = require("csurf");
const csrfProtection = csrf({
  cookie: true,
});


//next.js configuration
const dev = process.env.NODE_DEV !== "production";
const nextApp = next({ dev });
const port = 3000;
const handle = nextApp.getRequestHandler();

nextApp.prepare().then(() => {
  const app = express();

  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
  app.use(cors());
  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(500).send("Something went wrong!");
  });

  app.use(csrfProtection);
  app.use('/api', routes);

  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res);
  });

  //start server
  app.listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`listening on port ${port}`);
  });
});
```

routes/index.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const getCsrfToken = require('../controllers/csrf')
const postSignupQ = require("../controllers/postSignupQ");
const attachUser = require("../middleware/attachUser");

router.get("/csrfToken", getCsrfToken.getCsrfToken);
router.use(attachUser);
router.post("/signupQ", postSignupQ.postSignupQ);

module.exports = router
```

controllers/csrf.js

```
const getCsrfToken = (req, res) => {
  res.json({ csrfToken: req.csrfToken() }); 
};

module.exports = { getCsrfToken };
```

context - here I console.log(csrf):

```
   useEffect(() => {
    const getCsrfToken = async() => {
      const { data } = await axios.get('api/csrfToken');
      console.log("csurf", data);
      axios.defaults.headers['X-CSRF-Token'] = data.csrfToken;
    };

    getCsrfToken();
  }, []);
```

I don't understand why I get the error message, when I make a POST request for the first time and when I refresh the page everything works. What's the problem and how can I solve this?

**EDIT**
Thanks to Jack Yu the code snippets above are working. Maybe it can help someone else..

Comment: In your `server.js`, did you also use `app.use(csrf({cookie: true}))` ?

Comment: Yes. But I used it in routes/index.js, not in server.js. This is because routes/index.js is also the place where I make a call for the token. Could this be a problem?
Thanks for taking look at my code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### EDIT

I also found your api path might be wrong. In your axios is `await axios.get('csrfToken')`. But, I saw `/api/csrfToken` in your router. Change it to `await axios.get('/api/csrfToken')`

### Original Answer

In csurf package, when you use `csurf({cookie: true})` with cookie mode in middleware at multiple times, it'll break the csrf token in response header with **first time post**. You could take a look for more detail in [CSRF doesn't work on the first post attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64869650/csrf-doesnt-work-on-the-first-post-attempt/64877159#64877159), I've explain the reason in that post. So, there are two solutions you could use.

#### Solution 1

According to the comments, you use `app.use(csruf({cookie: true}))` in `server.js` and `router/index.js`. Remove the following line in your `router/index.js`. When you setup csruf in `server.js`, you could use `req.csrfToken()` in `controllers/csrf.js` without setting up csruf again.

```js
const csrf = require("csurf");
const csrfProtection = csrf({
  cookie: true,
});

router.use(csrfProtection);
```

#### Solution 2

You'll need to use `express-session` package. Add following code before the `csurf`. If you have `.use(csrf({cookie: true}))` in your `routes/index.js`, remove it.

```js
const session = require('express-session')
// mark1: change it to false
const csrfProtection = csrf({
  cookie: false,
});


// blablabla ... other code

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cors());
app.use(cookieParser());

// mark2: put here
app.use(session({
    name: "test",
    secret: "test",
    cookie: { maxAge: 3 * 60 * 60 * 1000 },
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}))
// put here

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(500).send("Something went wrong!");
});

app.use(csrfProtection);
app.use('/api', routes);
```

Then change `{cookie: true}` to `{cookie: false}` in **all csurf setting**. When you use session mode, you could use `csruf({cookie: false})` many times in middleware.

Comment: So I'm trying your solutions. Solution 1: I've removed router.use(csrfProtection) from routes/index.js. So I only have it in server.js. However, the error is still there - even when refreshing page it doesn't work. Solution 2: I get the error "misconfigured csrf". Any ideas what I could try?

Comment: Could you paste the server.js?

Comment: 1. Still happen invalid token in first time post even you restart your server? 2. I updated my answer, when using {cookie: false}, you'll need to use express-session package

Comment: Yes. I've restarted the server. Even with the express-session package the error is there. Is it possible that the order of the functions (endpoints and middleware) is somehow wrong?

Comment: @Ewax_Du I update the oder with solution 2, there are two marks you need to modify try it.

Comment: Thanks! But error is still there. I played a little with the code and the only way the app works by now is: Solution 1, but when everything csrf related is moved to routes/index.js. I still have to refresh the page, but at least I can log-in. I'm not sure if there is something wrong with the context (useEffect)? Should I get a new csrf token each time I make a call to a protected endpoint? By now I get only 1 token, even if I make calls to protected endpoints - so maybe thats the point?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227826/discussion-between-jack-yu-and-ewax-du).

Answer (score -1):

We need to pass a cookie in header like below:

```js
headerMaps.put("cookie", "_csrf=value; connect.sid=value; csrfToken=value")
```